# AsynkTask returning null on method

Tags: android, android-asynctask

The problem is that my method from doInBackground return 0 to onPostExecute , i tried a lot but dind't get how to fix it , please help

```
 @Override
  protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
  makeCount(URL_ORDERS_US,count);
  return null;
  }
```

Here is the method

```
 public void makeCount(String uri,int countnow){
        List<NameValuePair> paramUS = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(uri, "GET", paramUS, SavedToken);
        try {
            JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");
            JSONObject orders = data.getJSONObject("orders");
            Iterator<String> orderIterator = orders.keys();
            while (orderIterator.hasNext()) {
                try{
                JSONObject c = orders.getJSONObject(orderIterator.next());
                countnow++;
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }catch (JSONException e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }
```

and the onPostExecute

```
 @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        usac.setText(String.valueOf(count));
        pDialog.dismiss();
        }
```

Comment: the line "return null;" is always going to return null, I don't understand what you're trying to do

Comment: i want to count the number of json object entities , when methods find one it does ++ , i want to send the value from method in do in background to onPostExecute

Comment: Remove the `int countnow` parameter and move it out of the method.

Answer (score 0):

CountNow is passed by value as of any other parameter in java. Declare it as a member of the asynctask cuatom class u've created because you're just modifying a local copy and not the global behaviour u want to achieve

Comment: sir can you give a link reference please, i din't quete understand you because of my lack of knowledge on the subject

Answer (score 0):

Your `doInBackground` returns null. That `null` is argument of your `onPostExecute`. Note that you are not using String s argument at all in onPostExecute. You use `String.valueOf(count)`. Where `count' comes from?

Is this member variable of your AsyncTask ? if yes, it should work - according to 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html **Memory observability**

But your `count` member variable is never modified. You modify its copy - `countnow` parameter of makeCount function.

See [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value) for question where it is discussed how arguments are to the functions passed.

Comment: the value of count comes from makeCount method , count is declared as global var

Comment: @Alex I answered your question by editing my post. You modify only parameter _countnow_ not member variable _count_.

Answer (score 0):

Sir?,please do this..

```
public void makeCount(String uri,int countnow){
    List<NameValuePair> paramUS = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(uri, "GET", paramUS, SavedToken);
    try {
        JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");
        JSONObject orders = data.getJSONObject("orders");
        Iterator<String> orderIterator = orders.keys();
        while (orderIterator.hasNext()) {
            try{
            JSONObject c = orders.getJSONObject(orderIterator.next());
            publishProgress(countnow++);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }catch (JSONException e){e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

then here is where your publish progress goes

```
  @Override
  protected Integer onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) { // the integer means it takes int as a value..
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    //this methos updates the ui like the postexecute, just that in here you do,temporary
    //updates
}
```

i posted this code because my understanding from you was that you wanted to do something with the values or the number of times, thats why i posted it, my understanding could be wrong, if im wrong let me know, Sir Alex..

NOTE: there might be silly errors so please correct them, like spellings or code formattings, i did this without and edittor.. thanks..